# Error: NonUniqueResult - where to find rootcause

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to get from Repo a list of objects - Player - with the field `playerClub`. Created Query method in Repo:

```
@Repository
public interface PlayerRepository extends JpaRepository<Player, Long>{
    Player findAllByPlayerClub(Club club);
}
```

```
@Repository
public interface ClubRepository extends JpaRepository<Club, Long> {
    Club findByClubId(long clubId);
}
```

When  I use it, I get the error: NonUniqueResult

> javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 21
> at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
> at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1672) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
> at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]

I understand it means more than one result but I do need all of the Players.
Where I shall look for a solution...?

Comment: Your `findAllByPlayerClub` method returns `Player`. If you want a list of players it should return `List<Player>`.

Comment: Oh, learn how to format the question properly, please. [ask]